# For a robot in a maze, infer path from detected edges of walls

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, robotics

I am working on Robot Vision for navigating in a maze. I am pretty new to OpenCV and so far I have managed to read a test image of a maze as seen from the robot's eye view, detect the edges using Canny edge detection, focus on a Region of Interest and using HoughLinesP Transform detect where the walls meet the floor and draw a blue line.

[image: Blue lines inferred in the maze]

What I need to do now is calculate the center point between the two blue lines which are closer to the robot's camera and then do the same for the two lines which are more in the center of the image. Afterwards I want to connect the two center points to obtain a line.

Next step is to get the robot to follow this superimposed line.

Any help would be great :-)

Attached is an image created with my current script.

Here is my code:

```
# Original ideas abd code from 
# https://towardsdatascience.com/finding-driving-lane-line-live-with-opencv-f17c266f15db
# Testing edge detection for maze

import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("/home/pi/opencv/maze_test_images/maze1.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel_size = 5
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size,kernel_size),0)
low_threshold = 50
high_threshold = 150

edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray, low_threshold, high_threshold)

# create a mask of the edges image using cv2.filpoly()
mask = np.zeros_like(edges)
ignore_mask_color = 255

# define the Region of Interest (ROI) - source code sets as a trapezoid for roads
imshape = image.shape

vertices = np.array([[(0,imshape[0]),(100, 420), (1590, 420),(imshape[1],imshape[0])]], dtype=np.int32)

cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, ignore_mask_color)
masked_edges = cv2.bitwise_and(edges, mask)

# mybasic ROI bounded by a blue rectangle

#ROI = cv2.rectangle(image,(0,420),(1689,839),(0,255,0),3)

# define the Hough Transform parameters
rho = 2 # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
theta = np.pi/180 # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
threshold = 15     # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
min_line_length = 40 #minimum number of pixels making up a line
max_line_gap = 30    # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments

# make a blank the same size as the original image to draw on
line_image = np.copy(image)*0 

# run Hough on edge detected image
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(masked_edges, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]),min_line_length, max_line_gap)

for line in lines:
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
            cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),10)

# draw the line on the original image 
lines_edges = cv2.addWeighted(image, 0.8, line_image, 1, 0)
#return lines_edges

coord = np.where(np.all(lines_edges == (255,0,0), axis=-1))
print zip(coord[0], coord[1])


cv2.imshow("original", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow("edges", edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow("detected", lines_edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite("lanes_detected.jpg", lines_edges)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post some code for what you've tried so far, so that we can help you with more specific questions. General "How-To" type questions are usually considered off-topic.

Comment: I have added my code. What I am trying to do is be able to plot a line central to the walls of the maze (The lines now highlighted in blue) and get the robot to follow this central line. Just like a line follower but with a virtual line.

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that HoughLinesP finds the lines based on the given parameters and places the results as an np array in variable lines. The for loop then iterates through this variable and draws the lines on the original image using the start point and end point coordinates of each line as stored in lines. So without knowing another way to do what I want I could use the x and y coords and draw new lines using this data. I need to try and understand the maths equation to do this :-)